# one SQL query not run with same PDO connection?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Bellow query is working fine....

```
  $SQL =<<<'EOD'
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pard_host (
    host varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    db varchar(255),
    db_user varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    db_pass varchar(255)
    )
    EOD;

    $pardConfig->query($SQL);
```

But bellow query is not working with same PDO connection

```
$SQL =<<<'EOD'
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pard_host(
title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
online varchar(100),
offline varchar(100),
email varchar(100),
metades varchar(200),
metakey varchar(200),
copyright varchar(200),
host varchar(100),
database varchar(100),
username varchar(100),
password varchar(100)
)
EOD;

$pardConfig->query($SQL);
```

I want to know about the problem 2nd query has.I'm confusing now.can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error: you missed `)` here

```
online varchar(100,
                  ^------
```

You also used [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) `database` for column name, change it to other word

Comment: yes i got it but query is not working after adding the missed )

Comment: consider changing database to other word like ph_database